# Pygame: Draw single pixel

Tags: python, pygame

I'm looking for method that allow me to draw single pixel on display screen. For example when I click mouse, I want the position of clicked pixel to change color. I know how to read mouse pos, but I could not find simple pixel draw ( there is screen.fill method but it's not working as I want).

Comment: `surface.fill(COLOR, (pos, (1,1))` is not enough?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do this with [`surface.set_at()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_at):

```
surface.set_at((x, y), color)
```

You can also use [`pygame.gfxdraw.pixel()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.pixel):

```
from pygame import gfxdraw
gfxdraw.pixel(surface, x, y, color)
```

Do note, however, the warning:

> EXPERIMENTAL!: meaning this api may change, or dissapear in later
>   pygame releases. If you use this, your code will break with the next
>   pygame release.

You could use [`surface.fill()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.fill) to do the job too:

```
def pixel(surface, color, pos):
    surface.fill(color, (pos, (1, 1)))
```

You can also simply draw a line with the start and end points as the same:

```
def pixel(surface, color, pos):
    pygame.draw.line(surface, color, pos, pos)
```

Comment: I tried this, but I thought there is some kind of specific method to do that. For now I'll stay with that.

Answer (score 18):

The usual method of drawing a point on a *Surface* or the display is to use  [`pygame.Surface.set_at']:

```py
window_surface.set_at((x, y), my_color)
```

However, this function is very slow and leads to a massive lack of performance if more than 1 point is to be drawn.

Minimal example where each pixel is set separately: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-DrawPixel-1](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-DrawPixel-1#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)

    rect = pygame.Rect(window.get_rect().center, (0, 0)).inflate(*([min(window.get_size())//2]*2))
    
    for x in range(rect.width):
        u = x / (rect.width - 1)
        color = (round(u*255), 0, round((1-u)*255))
        for y in range(rect.height):
            window.set_at((rect.left + x, rect.top + y), color) 
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

Another option is to use a ["pygame.PixelArray"](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) object. This object enables direct pixel access to *Surface* objects. A *PixelArray* pixel item can be assigned directly. The pixel can be accessed by subscription. The PixelArray locks the *Surface*, You have to [`close()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray.close) it when you have changed the pixel:

```py
pixel_array = pygame.PixelArray(window_surface)

pixel_array[x, y] = my_color
pixel_array[start_x:end_x, start_y:end_y] = my_color

pixel_array.close()
```

Minimal example that set one line of pixels at once: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-DrawPixel-2](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-DrawPixel-2#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)

    rect = pygame.Rect(window.get_rect().center, (0, 0)).inflate(*([min(window.get_size())//2]*2))

    pixel_array = pygame.PixelArray(window)
    
    for x in range(rect.width):
        u = x / (rect.width - 1)
        color = (round(u*255), 0, round((1-u)*255))
        pixel_array[rect.left + x, rect.top:rect.bottom] = color 
    
    pixel_array.close()
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who are interested in a more modern answer to the question you can use [pygame.draw.circle()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) to draw a single pixel at a given position (or center).

```
pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, center, 0)
```

The documentation specifically says:

> radius (int or float) -- radius of the circle, measured from the center parameter, a radius of 0 will only draw the center pixel

Comment: The latest version of pygame 2.0.0 for pygame.draw.circle states:
Changed in pygame 2.0.0: ... Nothing is drawn when the radius is 0 (a pixel at the center coordinates used to be drawn when the radius equaled 0)... So drawing a circle with a zero radius no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that is to draw a line staring and ending at the same point.

```
pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,y), (x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

draw a single coloured pixel

```
def drawPoint(x,y,color):

    s = pygame.Surface((1,1))   # the object surface 1 x 1 pixel (a point!)

    s.fill(color)               # color as (r,g,b); e.g. (100,20,30)

# now get an object 'rectangle' from the object surface and place it at position x,y

    r,r.x,r.y = s.get_rect(),x,y    

    screen.blit(s,r)            # link the object rectangle to the object surface
```

of course you have to call:  pygame.display.update() once you have
drawn all the points you need, don't call update at every single point.

Answer (score 0):

```
# with this function, you can draw points and change the yer size
def point(surface, color, x, y, size):
    '''the surface need the information of the pygame window'''
    for i in range(0, size):
        pygame.draw.line(surface, color, (x, y-1), (x, y+2), abs(size))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).