# Why PyGame is not drawing a single pixel using .set_at?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to find a way to draw a line made of black pixels in PyGame. Following [Pygame: Draw single pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354638/pygame-draw-single-pixel), I end up with:
[image: pygame 1px width line]
using this code:

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 10

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
screen.fill(WHITE)

pygame.display.flip()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()

for i in range(100):
  screen.set_at((i, 100), BLACK)

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      exit()
  
  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(FPS)
```

I used [ColorSlurp](https://colorslurp.com/) to check the width.

**Why do I end up with a 4px wide line ? Is there a way to fix it to actually get a 1 pixel line width?**

### Notes

I thought maybe ColorSlurp was adding fake extra pixels on zoom (like "over zooming"). So I checked with HTML canvas, I got this:
[image: html canvas 1px test]

By zooming out, I get an actual 1 pixel wide line. So I have the same behavior but my computer can actually display a thiner line compared to what `.set_at(position, color)` on PyGame or `.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1)` on canvas create.

Comment: Is your display DPI scaled?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did not know what DPI was. Following:  I have a macbook pro, following https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl86d72b76/11.0/mac/11.0 I checked on different options, I always have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`set_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at) changes the color of a single pixel. However, if your display is DPI-scaled, the surface will be scaled up when the Pygame window is updated. You must disable scaling for the Pygame window. e.g. in windows you can do:

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```