# i cant seem to change the colors of individual pixels in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pixel

so basically when i run this code and press a key, then release, nothing happens, and ive tried so many fixes to it, but it doesnt seem to work

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
sh = 610
sw = 610
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sw,sh))
pygame.display.set_caption("randomized images")
running = True
img = pygame.Surface((sw,sh))
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            for x in range(0,sw):
                for y in range(0,sh):
                    img.set_at((x,y), (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)))
    screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

can someone help me out? its driving me insane

Comment: Your code works fine, however drawing 610*610 individual pixels takes a while. Note that `set_at` is not very performant and it takes time to execute it 372,100 times. See the answers to [Pygame: Draw single pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354638/pygame-draw-single-pixel) for better solutions.